# Squared brackets to set this properties in constructor

Tags: javascript, object, dom

I'm trying to gather all elements of my HTML document into an JS object.
See these two ways, the first works as expected, while using a contructor doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var elements1 = {};

document.querySelectorAll('*[id]').forEach(function(element) {
  elements1[element.id] = element;
});

var elements2 = new Elements();

function Elements() {
  document.querySelectorAll('*[id]').forEach(function(element) {
    this[element.id] = element;
  });
}

console.log(elements1);
console.log(elements2);
```

```html
<div id="division1"></div>
<div id="division2"></div>
<div id="division3"></div>
```

Comment: Your `this` points to `function (element)` and not to `function Elements()`

Comment: Welcome to SO.

First, define things before using them.

Second, if you define a function, use it as one. there is no `new` required. this would only be appliable to ES6 style class'

Comment: @StevenStark `new` is most certainly required if he wants to create a new object to store the references on.

Comment: @Pointy no, it is not here. `Elements` is a function. it doesn't return anything, so the variable assignment is also wrong.

Comment: Yes but calling it with `new` *creates* an object and that's the eventual value of `elements2`. Once the `.forEach()` is fixed, the newly-created object will contain the references.

Comment: @StevenStark Does it matter were I define my function, except for readability reasons? And then this is just how constructors are called, isn't it?

Comment: @Justinas I understand that `this` is covered, but what can I do about it?

Comment: @DonFuchs yes, it matters where you define your functions. If you're in a class, less so because the class as a whole is executed before the functions can be accessed, but in your example `Elements` will be undefined.

Comment: @Pointy you don't create an object by saying `var foo = new Function()`, that doesn't make sense. You'd just do `var foo = {}`, technically almost everything in js is an object, but's that's a gross misuse of that fact.

Comment: ?? You can definitely create an object by using `new`; why is it even there in the language otherwise? Now I'll agree that I don't see much *point* in that here, but in order for that second test to work using `new` makes as much sense as anything else in the question.

Comment: @Pointy no, `new Elements()` does NOT make any sense here, sorry but no.

Comment: Consider that `Elements.prototype` might be envisioned as containing some useful methods.

Comment: @StevenStark This mustn't make any sense as this is a minimal example. But still it does as `Elements()` encapsulates the non-trivial object preparation and can be used again later, when `document` has changed for example.

Comment: @StevenStark And it does not matter were `Elements()` is defined, just run above code snipped and see that it works, just that the created object is empty.

Comment: @DonFuchs Yes, it very much does matter!

Try running this in the console, ( use a NEW incognito window each time): `foo(); var foo = function(){ console.log("doesn't work") }` and you will see exactly why it does matter, where this works: `var foo = function(){ console.log("does work") }; foo()`

Comment: @DonFuchs assigning a variable to a function just to use it's scope at a later time is a HORRIBLE approach in every sense. do not do this.

Comment: @StevenStark I'm not using function expressions, that's the difference. Maybe you should check out https://javascript.info/function-expressions-arrows#function-expression-vs-function-declaration

Comment: @DonFuchs I fail to see your point. this is code smells, bud, sorry but it's true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In second example `this` points to wrong location.

```js
var elements1 = {};

document.querySelectorAll('*[id]').forEach(function(element) {
  elements1[element.id] = element;
});

var elements2 = new Elements();

function Elements() {
  var that = this;
  document.querySelectorAll('*[id]').forEach(function(element) {
    that[element.id] = element;
  });
}

console.log(elements1);
console.log(elements2);
```

```html
<div id="division1"></div>
<div id="division2"></div>
<div id="division3"></div>
```

Comment: @DonFuchs you can also pass `this` as the second argument to `.forEach()` and then `this` *inside* the `.forEach()` callback will have the desired value.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` value in your second function is pointing to the instance of that function.  To fix this you can use ES6 arrow functions which prevent them from creating their own scope.

```
function Elements() {
  document.querySelectorAll('*[id]').forEach((element) => {
    this[element.id] = element;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank godness, I like this better than setting `this = that`

Comment: @DonFuchs Happy to help!  Remember, arrow functions are your friend.